# Django rest raising error "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form." to angualar Http Client

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

The are any solutions to the problem but m not able to find the root cause and also to mention no of the solution is working in my case.

What I am trying to do is to upload a file to Django rest API from a angular Http Client Service.

I am taking up the input form the user passing to the service at the end I have declared a type specific for the type of model I am creating an object for but I am not getting the same error again and again.

I read some where that Django file uploader doesn't understand some char-set format but I still can't understand whats wrong with it.

```
var report = <CompleteReport> {
  title:'heelo',
  description:'sdfsdfs',
  author: 'report',
  article_upload_images: [uuid4(),],
  presentation_upload_images: [uuid4(),],
  report_article: article_object,
  report_image: image_object,
  report_podcast: podcast_object,
  report_presentation: presentation_object,
  report_video: video_object
};

let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Accept': 'application/json'
});

let options = {headers: headers};

return this.http.post<any>(url, report, options)
```